# Degree of covering map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ and local degree signs

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, orientation

This question is both about a specific problem and a soft question about these sorts of problems. I'm reading through Hatcher's textbook and having trouble dealing with signs when it comes to local degree calculations. Here is an example where I am struggling.

Let $f$ be the map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ that is the quotient by antipodal points. I want to show that when $n$ is odd, $f$ sends a generator of $H_n(S^n)$ to twice a generator of $H_n(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n)$. In order to do that, I can further consider the quotient $q: \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n \to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n/\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^{n-1} \cong S^n$. By the long exact sequence of $(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n, \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^{n-1})$, $q$ induces an isomorphism on homology so it suffices to show that $g :=q \circ f$ has degree $\pm 2$. Let $p$ be the north pole of $S^n$ (i.e. $p = (0, \ldots, 0, 1)$); then $g^{-1}(p)$ consists of $p$ and $-p$. I understand that $g$ is a local homeomorphism around both these points so the local degree is $\pm 1$, but I am not totally sure why the sign of the degrees should be the same.

My vague intuition: let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be neighbourhoods of $p$ and $-p$ that are mapped homeomorphically onto $V$ and let $\alpha$ be the antipodal map. Then $g_{U_1} = g_{U_2} \circ \alpha$, and $\alpha$ sends an oriented generator of $H_n(U_1, U_1 - \{p\})$ to an oriented generator of $H_n(U_2, U_2 - \{p\})$ because $n$ is odd. Therefore $g$ sends generators of both local homology groups to the same element in $H_n(S^n)$. Here I am using the term oriented generator to mean a generator that corresponds to the chosen generator of $H_n(S^n)$ under the isomorphisms $$
H_n(U_1, U_1 - \{p\}) \xrightarrow{i_*} H_n(S^n, S^n-\{p\}) \xleftarrow{j_*} H_n(S^n).$$
But I'd like a more rigorous justification, because I only know that $\alpha$ preserves orientation of a generator of $H_n(S^n)$, and not what it does to local homology groups. Therefore, I tried this: we have the commutative diagram:

[image]

The right square commmutes because the underlying maps do, and the left square commutes by naturality of the long exact sequence of homology. The oriented generator of $H_n(U_1, U_1 - \{p\})$ is $e_1 := i_*^{-1}j_*([e])$, where $[e]$ is a chosen generator for $H_n(S^n)$, and similarly for $H_n(U_2, U_2 - \{p\})$. By commutativity of the diagram, $$i_*\alpha_*([e_1]) = \alpha_* i_*([e_1]) = \alpha_* j_*([e]) = j_* \alpha_*([e]) = j_*([e])$$ where in the last equality I have used the fact that $\alpha_*: H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$ is identity when $n$ is odd. Therefore $\alpha_*([e_1]) = e_2$, i.e., $\alpha$ sends an oriented generator to an oriented generator.

1. Have I made any mistakes in this calculation?
2. Is there a faster way to rigourously calculate the local degrees in the above? By rigourous, I mean algebraically explicit and not relying on geometric intuition.
3. In general I appreciate geometric intuition, but I want to be able to show things algebraically rigourously as well. Is this sort of argument by commutative diagram the usual approach to determine the correct signs of local degrees?

Comment: If you want to understand degree on a rigorous level, I suggest supplementing Hatcher with a book on differential topology. For example, your maps $f$, $q$, $i$, $j$, etc. are all local diffeomorphisms at appropriate points, which allows you to use derivatives, determinants, etc. in calculating the degree.

Comment: @Lee Mosher You're right, I had a look at Milnor's definition of the degree for smooth maps and the connection from geometric intuition to the algebra was much more obvious. And I may be off base, but we might as well define the degree for spheres using the smooth definition and descend to homotopy classes of maps since each class is guaranteed to contain a smooth map by the Whitney approximation theorem. Thanks for the advice!